# Jquery Remote AutoComplete

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am trying to understand the following demo : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/

In the original demo , they send a request to `http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?`

And for example if the input is "New York" the request is the following  :

```
http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?callback=&q=New%20York&_=1419120068976
```

And the response from the server :

```
["New York Mills, MN, United States","New York Mills, NY, United States","New York, NY, United States","West New York, NJ, United States"]
```

Overall , I believe I understand how it works , now my problem is , that I am trying to do a single change on the code to my server.

```
http://s525504567.onlinehome.us/test/?
```

All I did was a simple php script to output the same result for NY

```
echo '["New York Mills, MN, United States","New York Mills, NY, United States","New York, NY, United States","West New York, NJ, United States"]';
```

The request would be :

```
http://s525504567.onlinehome.us/test/?&callback=jQuery1111008215739631306596_1419126149636&q=New+&_=1419126149640
```

And the output :

```
["New York Mills, MN, United States","New York Mills, NY, United States","New York, NY, United States","West New York, NJ, United States"]
```

But it is not working...

```
Original Pen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbxPva
Modified pen(only the url) : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvbGJY
```

The problem I am having is that it do not work. I do not understand what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script returns invalid jsonp. Loading your test script in browser window: http://s525504567.onlinehome.us/test/?&callback=jQuery1111008215739631306596_1419126149636&q=New+&_=1419126149640

Returns:

```
jQuery1111008215739631306596_1419126149636( {"total":1,"movies":[{false}
```

Since your test script isn't outputting syntactically valid JSON, your JavaScript callback execution fails.

You should learn to use the debugging tools available to you: your browser's developer tools provide a wealth of information about JavaScript errors, network requests, and other information to help you pinpoint your trouble.

Do this with the original pen, for example. The `Autocomplete` call http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity?&callback=jQuery111107159031711053103_1419138275032&q=new&_=1419138275033 returns a JSONP data payload:

```
jQuery111107159031711053103_1419138275032(["New Albany, IN, United States","New Albany, KS, United States","New Albany, MS, United States","New Albany, OH, United States","New Albany, PA, United States","New Albin, IA, United States","New Alexandria, PA, United States","New Almaden, CA, United States","NEW AMSTERDAM, EB, Guyana","New Athens, IL, United States","New Athens, OH, United States","New Auburn, MN, United States","New Auburn, WI, United States","New Augusta, MS, United States","New Baden, IL, United States","New Baden, TX, United States","New Baltimore, MI, United States","New Baltimore, NY, United States","New Baltimore, PA, United States","New Bavaria, OH, United States"]);
```

That `jQuery1111....` bit is important. It is the function that will be executed by the invoking script with the response data. You need to modify your server-side script to return JSONP, not just a bare array object, if you want to use this on a Codepen like you're doing.

Comment: That is because I was trying to solve the issue my own. Try now

Comment: My comment still stands. Your script is returning a straight-up array; it needs to be returning JavaScript that gets executed by the JSONP callback handler and interpreted. See edited answer.

Comment: When we are calling http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity from an application, is there a license that needs to be bought?